# Sync an iOS folder to Google drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I want to have two way sync between local iOS folder and google drive folder. Can someone suggest a way to achieve this? I was not able to find right google drive API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right google drive api is the google drive sdk https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: I went through google drive SDK. But i found an API which i have to manually sync data every time which is pretty inefficient. I am looking if there is a google provide API which will serve this purpose

Comment: That's right. You'll need to write your own sync algorithm

Comment: Has anyone found any library which is already taking care of this?